# Rotation compatibility for iOS 5.1 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, rotation, universal

In a **universal app** that needs to run both on **iOS 5.1** and **iOS 6.0** I use the above code to allow **rotation** in both versions, and both on the iPhone, both on iPad.
Is There a better way to do this, while maintaining compatibility between the two versions and without using deprecated functions?
With the above code I have some little issues in iPad with iOS 6.0, sometimes...

Thank you.

```
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
// Rotation for v. 5.1.1
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    // on iPad support all orientations
    return YES;
    }
else {
    // on iPhone/iPod support all orientations except Portrait Upside Down
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
return NO;
}



// Rotation 6.0

// Tell the system It should autorotate
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}

// Tell the system which initial orientation we want to have
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

}

// Tell the system what we support
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
// return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
// return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Add:
After some test I got again the bug also in simulator: the left part of slitViewController become black (non always) with the above errors (than it run again, rotating the iPad):

---

```
<Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0.
<Error>: CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextGetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextSetCompositeOperation: invalid context 0x0
<Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

...

---

Comment: What issues do you have on iPad with iOS6? Deprecated methods shouldn't do anything when run on iOS6.

Comment: Randomly sometime the upper system bar doesn't rotate; one time (iPad in landscape) the left part (table view in SplitViewController, corresponding to the popover in portrait) appeared wholly black (then it reappeared rotating the iPad)...

Comment: Is that happening on device, simulator or both?

Comment: also in simulator: see above the message, as I edited it, please

Comment: Do you solve it? Same issue for me